# which contract emit the Transfer event?

Tags: blockchain, tokens, erc-721, avalanche

let's say I minted an ERC721 NFT using smart "contract_one" and it was sold by another contract called "contract_two" in which contract the transfer event will trigger?

Answer (score 0):

for an **event** specifically, it depends on your contract's code and where you have defined emit/event.

Answer (score 0):

`Transfer` event is by default should be emited by `ERC20` and `ERC721` smart contract, the standard of ethereum. If your smart `contract B` is also emitting some event then it is upto that contract structure and design. So, if, let's say, the smart `contract B` is emitting some event like `Sold` then both the events are emited in single transaction `Transfer` event form ERC721 and `Sold` event contract B.